# How do I reduce the opacity of the 3D objects that are not selected upon mousedown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, 3d, three.js, webgl

Essentially, I was wondering how do I reduce the opacity of all the 3D objects within the scene that are not selected upon mousedown? That is, if I select one object (That object's opacity is 1) and the other's opacity reduces by a fixed number. Let's say, all the other objects are now at opacity .25? For example, how would I reduce the opacity of the cubes in this example when one of the cubes are selected?  http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes.html

Below is how I would do it using images and JQuery and I've seen numerous examples on how to do it on images but I haven't found any examples that use 3D objects.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
a{
text-decoration: none;
}
</style> 
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="images">
<a class="images" href="#">
    <img class="click" src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff.png&text=1" />
    <br/><br/>
</a>
<a class="images" href="#">
    <img class="click" src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff.png&text=2"/>
    <br/><br/>
</a>
<a class="images" href="#">
    <img class="click" src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff.png&text=3"/>
    <br/><br/>
</a>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$('a.images').click(function() {
// Make all images (except this) transparent
$('a.images').not(this).stop().animate({
    opacity: 0.4
}, 300);
// Make this opaque
$(this).stop().animate({
    opacity: 1.0
}, 300);
});
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You set the opacity when creating an object, like : `var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: '#ffffff', opacity: 0.5 } ) );`

Comment: Look in the source of the page you linked to. It is much more complicated than images, because in a 3D scene, you need a rayCaster to work out which cube is 'below' the mouse pointer at the time. Then you could just set the opacity of the others. Also, jQuery selectors don't work on three.js meshes as they are not page elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interactive cubes example that you referenced, add this:

```
if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

    for ( i = 0; i < objects.length; i++ ) {    
        objects[ i ].material.opacity = 0.25;
    }

    intersects[ 0 ].object.material.color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );
    intersects[ 0 ].object.material.opacity = 1;

}
```

If you are using webGL, then be sure to set `transparent = true` for your transparent objects. But remember, transparency is tricky in WebGL, and you will likely have a lot of artifacts.

three.js r.58

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot @WestLangley! Btw, if I wanted to retain the original color of the cube, I would just add  Iintersects[ 0 ].object.material.color.setHex( intersects.currentHex ); but funnily enough, the color that is revealed is pure black and the other cubes are shades of grey (cubes not selected). Where am I at fault and how do I fix it so that it retains the correct color?

Comment: If you need more help, please make a new post, and link to a live example (jsfiddle.net) if possible. But first, do your absolute best to figure it out yourself. I bet you can, actually. :-)

Comment: I probably can. Thanks @WestLangley!